# Scalar-by-vector derivative involving L2 norm and Hadamard product

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I have a function $f(\mathbf{x})$: $\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$f(\mathbf{x}) = \lvert \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x} \circ \mathbf{x})-\mathbf{b} \rvert^2$.

with $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ a constant matrix, $\mathbf{b}$ the known vector $\in \mathbb{R}^N$, $\lvert \cdot \rvert^2$ the $\ell_2$ norm and $\circ$ the hadamard product. I would like to know the expression about the gradient of $f$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the vector
$$w = A(x\circ x) - b$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \;\;\;\,=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
A:(B\circ C) &= (A\circ B):C \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
A:B &= B:A \;\;=\; B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of the above, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= w:w \\
df &= 2w:dw \\
 &= 2w:A\,(x\circ dx + dx\circ x) \\
 &= 2A^Tw:(2x\circ dx) \\
 &= (4x\circ A^Tw):dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 4x\circ A^Tw \\\\
}$$

---

Note that there are at least two types of solutions for $x$
which yield a gradient of zero.

The first is
$$x=0$$
and the second is a family of $2^N$ solutions which can be written
using the inverse matrix, an element-wise square root,
and a sign vector with elements $s_k=\pm 1$
$$\eqalign{
&x = s\circ\big(A^{-1}b\big)^{\circ\frac 12} \\
&x\circ x = A^{-1}b \\
}$$
The question in the comments is:

*If you use a gradient descent algorithm, which solution will it converge to?*

It likely depends on your initial guess for $x$, but it's possible that the iterations will be strongly attracted to one of the solutions no matter where you start the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation. In this expression, I see that the grad is 0 when x =0. So can we still solve the optimization problem of f using the class of gradient descent algorithm?

Comment: @Woodrow I updated my post to address your question.

Comment: Thank you very much!